# regsvr32, should i unregister before register again?

Tags: windows, com, regsvr32, typelib

**Scenario:**

- I installed the COM dll on client machine in c:\program.dll and invoked the following command to register: **regsvr32 "c:\program.dll"**
- I updated the dll with a new version, in the same directory as the installation **"c:\program.dll"**.

**Doubt:**

Before registering the new version of the dll, do I need to unregister the previous version first?

**regsvr32 "c:\program.dll" /u**

If yes, why?

Comment: `regsvr32` simply load your dll in memory (via `LoadLibrary`) and call `DllRegisterServer` or `DllUnregisterServer` exported function from your dll. so answer depend only on how this 2entry implemented in your dll. `regsvr32` unrelated here. usually not need unregister. you simply change registry values on new (paths, version)

Comment: if path of component the same - you can at all not make new registration (if it not say update version of interfaces/typelibs/etc)

Comment: Hi @RbMm, let's say this is a COM dll from a third party and I do not know anything about the internal implementation of these methods.

Comment: if nothing known about *dll* - how it internal implement register and unregister - impossible absolute exactly say. but almost always - unregister not need. you can just call [`DllRegisterServer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682162(v=vs.85).aspx) (via regsvr32) and all will be work.

Comment: So, would it be a good practice to unregister before you register?

Comment: i think that no. i don't know any situation when `DllUnregisterServer` can fail, if it was previous already called. usual this function simply add some entries to registry. and no different are this entries already set or no

Comment: This is a good way to create DLL Hell.  Right now it is too late to fix it, you should have unregistered the old version.  But you already overwrote that DLL so you can't do it anymore.  How much can go wrong depends on how many programs are around that were not recompiled and how thorough the 3rd party was about dealing with versioning.  Not much of a problem if it is only your program that uses it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should unregister the old version, using the `DllUnregisterServer` function of the existing DLL.

It won't make a difference if the new version being installed sets up the same registry keys, but keep in mind that the user may be downgrading to an earlier version that doesn't implement a particular class -- in which case that class would remain registered.

Comment: To be clear, you should unregister the DLL *then* replace it with the new version, *then* register again. There is virtually no value in replacing the DLL and then calling regsvr32 /u on it. If there is a difference between the two DLLs in registry data, it's almost guaranteed that the new DLL doesn't know about removing the obsolete data of the old DLL.

Comment: This comment should be added to Simon's answer.